# Creating an std::vector<A&> and fillng it with classes derived from A

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

I want to create an `std::vector<A&>` and fill it with elements of class `B` and `C`, which derive from `A`.

```
struct A {
    virtual void print (){std::cout << "A" <<std::endl;}
};

struct B : public A {
    void print (){std::cout << "B" <<std::endl;}
};

struct C : public A {
    void print (){std::cout << "C" <<std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;
    std::vector<A&> vec{b,c};
    for(auto &e : vec)
    {
        e.print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know it can be done with ptr but my question if for reference

Comment: You can use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` if you want value semantics, i.e., if you want to (logically) store the elements inside the vector instead of filling the vector with references/pointers to externally stored elements, which is error-prone because you are responsible for regulating the lifetime of these elements.

Comment: By the way, please try to avoid `std::endl` when the flushing semantics is not needed.  `std::endl` flushes the buffer, while `\n` does not.  Unnecessary flushing can cause performance degradation.  See [`std::endl` vs `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/9716597).